# How to calculate the distance from target to each node in binary search tree with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I just started learning about binary search trees and the like and I am trying to find the distance from target to each node in binary search tree. Its really difficult and its really hard to find examples with javascript when it comes to data structures. Would be super thankful for any help!

```
        7
      /   \
     4     8
    / \   / \
   3   6 
  /
 2

for the traget of 6, my output should be {7: 2, 4:1, 3:2, 2:3, 8:3, 6:0}
```

What I have so far:

```
class Node {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

const calculate = (node, target) => {
  let counter = 0;
  const nodesAndThereDistances = {}

  if (!node) {
    return null;
  }
  const inner = (node, target) => {
    if (!node) {
      return null;
    }

    if (node.data !== target) {
      counter++;
      nodesAndThereDistances[node.data] = counter;
      if (node.left, target) {
        inner(node.left, target)
      }
      if (node.right, target) {
        inner(node.right, target)
      }
    } else {
      return nodesAndThereDistances;
    }
  }
  inner(node, target)
  return nodesAndThereDistances;
}

calculate(node1, 6)
```

Comment: What is your overall goal? A binary _search_ tree is about narrowing down to find a value. You want to find the distance between two items in the original list, or between where they happen to fall in your algorithm's abstract sorting procedure? Also, can there be duplicates (i.e. more than one match for a given value)? If so you will have multiple possibilities. Also, nodesAndThereDistances drives me nuts. "Their" differences. ;)

Comment: so the question is the following: i have multiple nodes. no dublicates. each node is only connected to 2 other nodes. calculate the distance of each node to the given target. I just started learning ds and actually it doesnt have to be a binary search tree i guess but could be also a binary tree (not sure if it matters in this case). Also yes, the name is not the best :))

Comment: So your current code calculates the distance to the root node, not to the target, right?

Comment: I tried to count distance to target but was counting target -root node first. my code is just wrong and I dont know how to actually do that